# Contains certain text but does not contain certain img, apply a css style to that

Tags: jquery

How can i express the following in jquery?

Apply a yellow background to every td on a table that contains "$" but does NOT contain img src="images/plus.gif"

I could do it just for the contain part using:

```
$("#SubscribersManageList tr:contains('$')").css("background", "yellow");
```

But its not what i want, what i want is to select those tr that CONTAIN "$" but DONT contain the image src="images/plus.gif", and then apply yellow background to those tr.

Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the [:not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [:has()](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selectors:

```
$("#SubscribersManageList td:contains('$'):not(:has(img[src='images/plus.gif']))")
    .css("background", "yellow");
```

You can test it in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SjzZD/).

Answer (score 1):

[**How is this for you**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/Rq5sw/)?

```
$('#SubscribersManageList tr:contains("$"):not(:has(img[src="images/plus.gif"]))').css("background-color", "yellow");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.not()` to filter those out.

```
$("#SubscribersManageList tr:contains('$')").not(:has('img[src|="images/plus.gif"]')).css("background", "yellow");
```

The expression

```
.not(:has(img[src|="images/plus.gif"]))
```

says do not select any child `img` whose `src` is `"images/plus.gif"`